# how to update two column with two different conditions for each column in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have two columns in my database table. i want to update both the columns in a single query but with two different conditions for each column. 
how to achieve this..??
Please Help.

Thanks in Advance.

I am using mysql database.

Comment: here is my code: 
mysql_query("UPDATE import SET customer_name='N/A' WHERE customer_name= '' ");
mysql_query("UPDATE import SET city='N/A' WHERE city='' ");
I want to combine these two queries

Comment: Do you mean two conditions as in 
Col1 = blah AND Col2 = blah
Or do you want to update all rows where col1 = blah OR col2 = blah?

Comment: What condition you want to put?

Comment: i want to update all rows in my table containing column name as customer_name where customer_name=""; same stands for column city.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
UPDATE import 
SET customer_name = case when customer_name = '' 
                         then 'N/A' 
                         else customer_name 
                    end,
    city = case when city = '' 
                then 'N/A' 
                else city 
           end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
UPDATE import SET 
       customer_name 
         CASE 
            WHEN customer_name= '' 
                THEN 'N/A' 
            ELSE custore_name 
         END, 
        city
          CASE 
             WHEN city='' 
                 THEN 'N/A'
             ELSE city 
         END
```

Comment: Thanks alot guys.. task completed successfully

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear, what you want to do, but how about:

update ...... set column1 = if(condition_column1 = 1, 'some_value', column1), column2 = if(condition_column2 = 2, 'other_value', column2)

this will work the same way as:

update ...... set column1 = 'some_value' where condition_column1 = 1

update ...... set column2 = 'other_value' where condition_column2 = 2